# How to count the number of elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, count

I need to write a python function that will count all the elements in a list, including those elements in a nested list.

Example, `len()` is built in function, `at_len()` is the function I want to create:

```
len( [1, 2] )  ---> 2

at_len( [1, 2] ) ---> 2

len( [ [1, 2], 3 ] ) ---> 2

at_len( [ [1, 2], 3 ] ) ---> 3

len( [1, 2, 'three', [1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b'] ], 5] )  --> 5

at_len( [1, 2, 'three', [1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b'] ], 5] )  --> 9
```

I need to be able to count those elements that are in nested lists. This is the code that I have, as well as the output I am getting.

```
def at_len(element_list):
    count = 0
    for each_item in element_list:
            if isinstance(each_item, list):
                    at_len(each_item)
            else:
                    count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

output:

```
at_len(['hello',1,2,'three',[1,'two',3]]) --> 3, 4 (should be 7)

at_len([1,2,[1,2,3]]) --> 3, 2 (should be 5)
```

I think I am close, but for some reason it prints out two counts instead of having them added together to get the correct total.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `at_len(each_item)` by `count += at_len(each_item)` and then return `count` (instead of printing).

It's printing twice because of the recursive call.  The print command is within the function.  Also notice that total is given a value but never used.  Instead do it as

```
def at_len(element_list):
    count = 0
    for each_item in element_list:
            if isinstance(each_item, list):
                    count += at_len(each_item)
            else:
                    count += 1
    return count
```

then just call it as:

```
print(at_len(yourlist))
```

Comment: by 30 seconds I believe.  Someone else posted an answer with flattening the list first, but it's gone.  I thought that was a nice idea.

Comment: Meh ... Wasteful just to get a count.  Also, flattening the list wasn't as easy as they thought (dealing with iterable and non-iterable items is a bit tricky in a comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

The whole function is really nothing more than:

```
def at_len(xs):
    return sum(at_len(x) for x in xs) if isinstance(xs, list) else 1
```

Or if you need it to not just work for lists:

```
from typing import Iterable


def at_len(xs):
    return sum(at_len(x) for x in xs) if isinstance(xs, Iterable) else 1
```